# Using Open with a filename that contains ":"

Tags: files-and-directories, windows

I am writing some data to a .txt file. I am using Open[] to create the text file in the directory I want and then Write[] and WriteString[]. (I am using FileNameJoin[] to create the actual filenames). I tried this out using a test file, called test.txt (and stored in the appropriate directory), it opens, writes to, and closes the file how I want. However, every time the notebook is run, I want to create a new output .txt file, so the files are named based on the date and time (in 24 hours), so part of the filename looks like HH:MM:SS. So, I am running something that looks like:

```
filename = 
  FileNameJoin[{"C:", "Users", "Me", "Dir1", "Dir2", 
"2019-07-0810:59:01.txt"}];
f=OpenWrite[filename]
```

Mathematica gives this error:

```
OpenWrite::noopen: Cannot open C:\Users\Me\Dir1\Dir2\2019-07-0810:59:01.txt.
```

I *think* what it doesn't like is the colons, since if I replace : with ; it opens/creates the file just fine (and it can open a file with just the date as the name). However, this is kind of ugly, and I would really prefer to use : instead.

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks you guys!

Comment: Personally, I solve this problem be replacing XX : YY : 
  ZZ by XXhYYmZZs in the name of the file. Here is the code : 
    `StringReplace[DateString[], 
       h : (_ ~~ _) ~~ ":" ~~ m : (_ ~~ _) ~~ ":" ~~ s : (_ ~~ _) :> 
        h ~~ "h" ~~ m ~~ "m" ~~ s ~~ "s"]`.
      It solves a second problem too : 
      sometimes (depending on the operating system) the seconds have 
decimals (10.45 for instance)

Comment: If you really want to put colons in file names, I suggest you use Linux.  However, even there, I think they are better avoided.

Comment: Using the StringReplace info from @andre314, you might also consider using DateString["ISODateTime"] such as this: StringReplace[DateString["ISODateTime"],  h : (_ ~~ _) ~~ ":" ~~ m : (_ ~~ _) ~~ ":" ~~ s : (_ ~~ _) :>  h ~~ "h" ~~ m ~~ "m" ~~ s ~~ "s"]   The result is a more compact representation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible. A colon is not a valid character in a file name on Windows.

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/filename

Comment: You're right @Szabolcs, thanks! I am just so used to Linux.

Comment: Even if valid, it would be prone to all sort of problems. I would avoid spaces, most symbols and long strings in filenames as much as possible.